# How can I get the Parallels Desktop Application Icons in Launchpad?

Tags: macos, parallels-desktop, launchpad

I have the opposite problem of [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/20024/218); I have [Parallels Desktop 6](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/) installed and while I do have the [Applications folder in the dock](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/13980/218), I don't have links to any of these applications in Launchpad.

How can I get these application icons in Launchpad? I'm aware that Parallels has the [following knowledge base article](http://kb.parallels.com/111995) which says that there is going to be a folder in Launchpad, but that's not what I want. I'm looking for a way to get all the applications icon to be visible in Launchpad, similar to this:

[image]

Note: I had Parallels installed on Snow Leopard (before I had Launchpad), and now I am using Lion.

Answer (score 2):

To add an application to Launchpad, you can simply drag it to Launchpad in the Dock.

[image]

But be careful — currently there's no way to *remove* something from Launchpad that you've added.

(And if you have items in a folder in Launchpad, you can easily drag them out and organize them as you wish.)